# Acceso de angular 4 a php no recibe el JSON

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs-2.0, typescript

Buen Dia, tengo un problema, tengo mi archivo `JSON` por xampp, y efectivamente este código me extrae los datos que necesito en `JSON`.
En la parte de `PHP`, si me recibe archivos `JSON` y los inserta a la base de datos muy bien, pero al trabajar con angular, le envio los datos que recojo en `HTML`, que efectivamente los combierte en `JSON` pero no le pasa estos archivos `JSON` a `PHP` para que los inserte a la base de datos.

La variable this.url = "http://localhost/app-backend/index.php/"

El link del index es el url + Datos_Sencibilizacion

y evidencian que si se encuentra el `JSON` que quiero ver en angular o que tambien quiero importarlo a `PHP` para insertarlo

```js
getSencibilizacion(): Observable < SencibilizacionModel[] > {
  return this._http
    .get(this.url + 'Datos_Sencibilizacion')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error))
}



//SECCION POST


postSencibilizacion(Dato_sencibilizacion: SencibilizacionModel) {
  let json = JSON.stringify(Dato_sencibilizacion);
  let params = 'json=' + json;
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
  });

  return this._http
    .post(this.url + 'Datos_Sencibilizacion', params, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error))
}
```

```css
public logout(): void {
  console.log(this.authenticationService.logout()) this.authenticationService.logout().subscribe( response=> {
    if(response) {
      console.log(response);
      this.storageService.logout();
    }
  }
  );
}

;
onSubmit() {
  this.sencibilizacionService.postSencibilizacion(this.Dato_sencibilizacion).subscribe( response=> {
    if(response.code==200) {
      this.authenticationService.logout();
    }
    else {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
  , error=> {
    console.log(<any>error);
  }
  );
}

;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$serverName = '****';
$connectionInfo = array( "database"=>"***", "UID"=>"***", "PWD"=>"***", "Characterset"=>"UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


//Configuracion de Cabeceras
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
};


$app->get('/Datos_Sencibilizacion', function() use($conn, $app){
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Datos_Sencibilizacion;';
 $insert = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $sql);

$rows = array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $insert, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){  
  $rows[] = $row;
}

 $result = array(
   'status' => 'success',
   'code'  => 200,
   'data' => $rows
  );

 echo json_encode($result);
});



$app->post ('/Datos_Sencibilizacion', function() use($app, $conn){
    
 $json = $app->request->post('json');
 $data = json_decode($json, true);


    if(!isset($data['Fecha'])){
        $data['Fecha']="NULL";
    }
    if(!isset($data['Nobre_Propietario'])){
        $data['Nobre_Propietario']="NULL";
    }
    if(!isset($data['Nobre_Establecimiento'])){
        $data['Nobre_Establecimiento']="NULL";
    }
    if(!isset($data['Direccion_Establecimiento'])){
        $data['Direccion_Establecimiento']="NULL";
    }
    if(!isset($data['Actividad_Economica'])){
        $data['Actividad_Economica']="NULL";
    }
    if(!isset($data['Telefono_Propietario'])){
        $data['Telefono_Propietario']=0;
    }
    if(!isset($data['Firma'])){
        $data['Firma']="0";
    }

    
                
    $query = "  INSERT INTO Datos_Sencibilizacion
                VALUES (".
                "'{$data['Fecha']}',".
                "'{$data['Nobre_Propietario']}',".
                "'{$data['Nobre_Establecimiento']}',".
                "'{$data['Direccion_Establecimiento']}',".
                "'{$data['Actividad_Economica']}',".
                "{$data['Telefono_Propietario']},".
                "'{$data['Firma']}'".
                ");";
    
 
    $insert = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $query);
 
        $result = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'code' => 404,
            'message' => 'Dato NO creado correctamente'
    );

    if($insert){
        $result = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'code' => 200,
            'message' => 'Dato creado correctamente'
        );
    }
    echo json_encode ($result);
});

$app->run();

?>
```

---

En este caso el login de mi proyecto se daño, al quitar la libreria CoreModule
abria una solucion para dejar el login sin esta libreria?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: David, bienvenido a SOes. Tu pregunta es un poco confusa. ¿si tienes algún problema? Porque estas diciendo al principio que tienes un problema y despues dices que tu codigo es efectivo en lo que tiene que hacer. Si es lo contrario, ¿cual es tu problema?

Comment: LA PARTE DE PHP ES CORRECTA, PERO EL ERROR ES QUE EL JSON QUE TENGO EN ANGULAR NO LO RECIBE PHP PARA INSERTARLO EN SQLSERVER, NO SE SI NO LO RECIBE SI LLEGA MAL O NO TIENE LA CONEXION CORRECTA

Comment: Entiendo. Gracias por editar tu pregunta y poner mas información. Solo como una sugerencia, cuando escribes con mayúsculas (en internet) es el equivalente a estar gritando, asi que te aconsejo que no lo hagas. Estoy seguro que pronto obtendras una buena respuesta.

Comment: Kenny que pena contigo, creeme que no era mi intencion, gracias a ti por darme consejos es mi primera pregunta por aqui, y agradesco tus consejos, si espero una respuesta y poder recibir mi dato JSON por api rest y ingresarlo a la base de datos

Comment: No hay problema David, no te preocupes. Que bueno que seas abierto a sugerencias. He editado tus etiquetas para que la pregunta atraiga mas atención. Si estuviera un poco mas avanzado en Angular te responderia, pero por el momento no puedo. Saludos!

Comment: Para que te podamos ayudar necesitamos saber que error te esta dando el api, por lo tanto, abre la consola de chrome, y mira en la pestaña network, alli te dara info sobre la request.

Comment: Puedes probar a cambiar este:
    .post(this.url + 'Datos_Sencibilizacion', params, {headers: headers})

Comment: Hola, Muchas Gracias por sus aportes, ya pude resolver el problema al parecer tiene conflictos con la librería [CoreModule] , al quitar esto ya funciona, pero en el login del programa se daño y no funciona

Comment: Buenas Tardes realizando el seguimiento encontre que esta funcion de fake-backend.ts es el que me daña mi programa. pero lo necesito para el login, no se si podria adaptarlo para que no genere problemas, alguien me podria ayudar?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Tardes realizando el seguimiento encontre que esta funcion de fake-backend.ts es el que me daña mi programa. pero lo necesito para el login, no se si podria adaptarlo para que no genere problemas, alguien me podria ayudar? 
//

```html
import {Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod, ResponseType} from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import {User} from "../models/user.model";
import {USERS} from "../mocks/mock-users";

class MockError extends Response implements Error {
  name:any;
  message:any;
}

export function fakeBackendFactory (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) {
  backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // fake authenticate api end point
      if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate/login') && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Post) {
        let params = JSON.parse(connection.request.getBody());

        // check user credentials and return fake jwt token if valid
        let found: User = USERS.find((user: User) => {return (params.username === user.username);});
        if (found) {
          if(params.password === found.password) {
            connection.mockRespond(new Response(
              new ResponseOptions({status: 200, body: {token: 'fake-token-jwt', user: found}})
            ));
          }else{
            connection.mockError(new MockError(new ResponseOptions({type:ResponseType.Error, status:400, body: JSON.stringify({code: 2, message: 'The password does not match '})})));
          }
        } else {
          connection.mockError(new MockError(new ResponseOptions({type:ResponseType.Error, status:400, body: JSON.stringify({code: 1, message: 'Username does not exists'})})));
        }

      }

      if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate/logout') && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Post) {
        let params = JSON.parse(connection.request.getBody());
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(
          new ResponseOptions({status: 200, body: true})
        ));
      }
    }, 500);

  });

  return new Http(backend, options);
}

export let fakeBackendProvider = {
  // use fake backend in place of Http service for backend-less development
  provide: Http,
  useFactory: fakeBackendFactory,
  deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Hace poco hice un login con ionic, es casi igual a angular, ya que me pides un posible ejemplo aquí esta.

Del lado del cliente puede hacer algo como:

```
let email = "foo@gmail.com";
let password = "var_password";

this.http.post("url del archivo del servidor", 
  '{"task":"login", "data":{"email":"' + email + '","password":"' + password + '"}}')
  .subscribe(response => {
   console.log(response);
   let data = JSON.parse(response["_body"]);
   console.log("Has algo con lo que regreso el servidor: " + data);
 }, fail => {
    console.log(fail);
 });
```

En la parte del servidor con php:

```
<?php
// Estos renglones los usa google chrome para cuestiones de seguridad.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache por un dia
}
// Los encabezados Access-Control se reciben durante las peticiones OPTIONS
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}

// Aqui empieza el codigo interesante.
include_once "tu conexion sql";
// file_get_contents("php://input") toma cualquier valor que entre por POST.
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata)) {
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    switch ($request->task) {
        case 'login':
            // se espera un json como: {"task": "login", "data": {"email": "email", "password": "password"}}
            echo login($conn, $request->data);
            break;
        case 'otro_caso':
            // En otro_caso diferente de login
            break;
        default:
            echo json_encode("No se realizo ninguna accion");
            break;
    }
}
/**
 * Selecciona en de la base de datos la información correspondiente al correo 
 * electrónico y contraseña que se envió y compara la contraseña en la consulta con la que regreso de sql,
 * si coinciden se le regresa al usuario su información.
 * @param type $conn Es un objeto con la información para la conexión a la base de datos.
 * @param type $query Es la información de la consulta a realizar.
 * @return String Regresa la información del usuario o un mensaje de error.
 */
function login($conn, $data) {
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT id, name, password, email FROM usuarios WHERE email = '".$data->email."';");
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        while($fila = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $temp = array();
            foreach ($fila as $i => $valor) {
                $temp[$i] = utf8_encode($valor);
            }
            $resultd_arr[] = $temp;
        }
        $query->free();
        $conn->close();
        if ($resultd_arr[0]["password"] == $data->password){
            // todo correcto
            return json_encode('{"id": "'.$resultd_arr[0]["id"].'", "name": "'.$resultd_arr[0]["name"].'", "email": "'.$resultd_arr[0]["email"].'"}');
        } else {
            // password incorrercto
            return json_encode("incorrecto");
        }
    } else {
        // email incorrecto
        return json_encode("incorrecto");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta mal escrita esta parte:

```
let params = 'json=' + json;
```

Al guardar ese texto así ya no es un json, lo correcto seria algo así:

```
let params = '{"json":' + json + '}';
```

Comment: Gracias @JuanLozoya Pero El  JSON Funciona a la perfección con el =, el error era una función con Mocks en el login y generaba conflicto lo des habilite y ya funciono bien, solo que haro el login quedo sin funcionar, no se si tendras alguna ayuda para hacer otro login

Comment: @DaVidRoa Si el problema es el login podrías hacer otra pregunta.

Comment: @JesseR.Jose El problema en un principio, fue el acceso de angular 4 ha php para la inserción de datos, resulto que el error estaba en la función que subi de los **mocks** que se utilizan para la autenticacion del login, por eso recurrí a diseñar otro login en angular sin que genere conflicto, realiza otro login y no me genera ya problema, ya en el transcurso del día les compartiré, la solución del error principal y el nuevo login que funciona, Gracias por tu interés